# Perl Regex to extract column name and value from Insert SQL

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone please help me to get extract column name and value in a perl scalar variable .

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 ) VALUES (1, 'Hi', 'A,B', '', null)
```

**Result** As a result I want to store key and value in Map kind of variable.

```
column1 1
column2 'Hi'
column3 'A,B'
column4 
column5 null
```

Comment: What you're showing is not really a scalar. Unless you want it to be a block of text with newlines.

Comment: I want to store the result in <key , value> format in a variable.

Answer (score 3):

I would not do this with regular expressions. SQL is a complicated language. Reinventing the wheel is not very smart. My approach uses [SQL::Statement](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Statement), which is the underlying tool used by many DBI drivers that interact with things that are not actually relational databases, like DBD::CSV.

It can be used to turn the SQL statement into a data structure, which then can be used to look up what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use SQL::Statement;
use List::MoreUtils 'zip';
use Data::Printer;

my $sql = q{INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5) VALUES (1, 'Hi', 'A,B', '', null )};

my $parser = SQL::Parser->new;
my $stmt = SQL::Statement->new($sql, $parser);

my @col_names = map { $_->{value} } @{ $stmt->column_defs };
(my $tmp) = $stmt->row_values;
my @row_values = @$tmp;

my %pairs = zip @col_names, @row_values;
p %pairs;
```

The output is:

```
{
    column1   1,
    column2   "Hi",
    column3   "A,B",
    column4   "",
    column5   undef
}
```

Note that strings and barewords (for lack of a better name) are both treated as strings. I have not figured out why yet.

In general, you have to read [SQL::Statement::Structure](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SQL-Statement/lib/SQL/Statement/Structure.pod) to understand how this works. But it's noteable that at least in my version 1.407 of SQL::Statement things are different than in the documentation. The `column_defs` method returns hash refs and those don't have a `name` item. The synopsis of the docs also lets one asume that what's returned by `column_defs` is intended to be a hash ref and not an object as claimed further down in the docs.

Anyway, this approach still works.

Comment: Can't locate object method "column_defs" via package "SQL::Statement" at test.pl. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: @amicngh what version of SQL::Statement did you install? Run `perl -MSQL::Statement\ 999` on the command line and mind the space after the backslash.

Comment: I am running it on Windows using ActivePerl. Following is output.
C:\AAMyCSRepo\developments\scripts>perl -MSQL::Statement\ 999
Can't open perl script "999": No such file or directory

Comment: In Statement.pm I can see use 5.008; And $VERSION = '1.26';

Comment: @amicngh Oh. Ok. Did you install it with the Perl Package Manager or was it already there? If you open the Package Manager Window and search installed packages for `SQL-Statement` it should tell you the version. I don't have a Windows machine to try. The `use 5.008` is not about the version of the code. It's [a pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) that tells Perl that this code needs at least a Perl of version 5.008 or otherwise it cannot be run. There might be a `our $VERSION = ...` in that file. If you see that, check it.

Comment: I see that version is  '0.1016'. I just downloaded v1.4.10 and replaced older one but still same issue

Comment: Did you copy my full example into a new file and ran that, or did you incorporate it directly into your code?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store the result in `<key , value>` format in a variable

Then you're looking for a [hash](https://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes).

See the below approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $data = q!INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 ) VALUES (1, 'Hi', 'AB', '', null)!;
my %column_value_pair;

if ($data =~ m!\((.*)\).*VALUES.*\((.*)\)!g){
    my @columns = split /,/, $1;
    my @values = split /,/, $2;

    #remove leading and trailing spaces
    $_ =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g foreach @columns, @values;

    @column_value_pair{@columns} = @values;
}

p %column_value_pair;
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl 
{
    column1   1,
    column2   "'Hi'",
    column3   "'AB'",
    column4   "''",
    column5   "null"
}
```

Note: I have not handled the case where value contains comma, for example `'A,B'`. I leave that to you as an exercise. Hint: split using comma as separator will also split A,B.

Comment: `@column_value_pair{@columns} = @values`